# To find domain on which given function is injective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The given function is
$f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$.
The question says on which of the following domains, $f$ is injective. And given options are natural numbers, integers, rationals and irrationals.

I started to solve the problem in this way. I was trying to find conditions on two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that they are distinct but still we get $f(a)=f(b).$

Considering $f(a)=f(b)$, I arrived at following condition,
$a(b^2+1)=b(a^2+1)$.

But I am not sure what to conclude from this condition.

Any help or hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Your condition can be written as

$$(b-a)(ab-1)=0$$
So, the function will be injective in a domain where we can't find $ a\ne b$ satisfying $ ab=1$.

You can also observe that
$$(\forall x\ne 0)\;\; f(\frac 1x)=f(x)$$

the function is injective at
$(-\infty,-1]\;,\; [-1,1] $ and $[1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$f(a)=f(b)\implies (b-a)(ab-1)=0.$$